# Touch pad Document

Tags: pcb, touchscreen, keypad, touch

I tear down one touch pad and wonder what technology they used.
I am sharing picture of it.

Any one know what is used for touch sense ? (my guess is capacitive).

I am planning to design one by myself. Anyone know where I can find whitepaper for this tech or any document or reference design.
Any pointer will do too.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: look at application guides for touch capable microcontrollers

Comment: Is there any IC available  that do the touch sensing and communicate with main microcontroller over I2C or any other similar method ?

Comment: probably yes ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If anyone have any experience with such IC please share.